# Parse XML with BIRT

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xpath, birt

I am pretty new to BIRT and XML but trying to fix a performance issue. Right now we have a report that is using a big XML file as the data source and it is taking to long to load. So I've been exploring different options. I found that you can use a Scripted Data Source and use java to parse the XML.

My problem is that it is leaving some of rows blank even if there is information in the XML file.

I have a test XML file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<library>
    <book category="COOKING">
        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author name="Giada De Laurentiis" country="it"/>
        <year>2005</year>
        <info>asdfghjkl</info>
    </book>    
    <book category="CHILDREN">
        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
        <author name="J K. Rowling" country="uk" />
        <year>2005</year>
        <info>asdfghjkl</info>
    </book>    
    <book category="WEB">
        <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>

        <author name="James McGovern" country="us" />
        <author name="Per Bothner" country="us" />
        <info>asdfghjkl</info>
    </book>    
    <book category="WEB">
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <author name="Erik T. Ray" country="us" />
        <year>2003</year>
        <info>asdfghjkl</info>
    </book>
</library>
```

In my Data Set under open I have

```
importPackage(javax.xml.parsers);
importPackage(javax.xml.xpath);
importPackage(org.w3c.dom);
importPackage(org.xml.sax);

var factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
var builder = null;
 doc = null;
var expr = null;

factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
doc = builder.parse(params["FileName"].value);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

// create an XPathFactory
var xFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

// create an XPath object
 xpath = xFactory.newXPath();

// compile the XPath expression
expr = xpath.compile("/library/*");
// run the query and get a nodeset
var result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

//initialize object variables to be used in the fetch method
nodes = result;

x = 0;
y = 0;

cnt = nodes.getLength();
```

Under fetch I have

```
var lboolAllowed = false;

if (x < cnt)
{

    var nodeList = nodes.item(x).getChildNodes();
    var nodeListLength = nodes.item(x).getChildNodes().getLength();
    for(var i=0; i<nodeListLength; i++)
    {
        var nodeName = nodeList.item(i).getNodeName();
        var nodeText = nodeList.item(i).getTextContent();
        if(nodeName == "category")
        {
            row["category"] = nodeText;
        }
        if(nodeName == "year")
        {
            row["year"] = nodeText;
        }
        else if(nodeName == "info")
        {
            row["info"] = nodeText;
        }
        else if(nodeName == "title")
        {
        row["title"] = nodeText;
        }
        else if(nodeName == "author")
        {
        row["author"] = nodeText;
        }
        else if(nodeName == "country")
        {
        row["country"] = nodeText;
        }

        y++
    }   
    x++;
    y=0;
    return (true);

    }
return (false);
```

Then I have a Report Parameter called FileName that points to where the XML file is.
The rows that are coming up blank are category, author and country. I am using version 3.2.23.
Here is the XML Source from the report if that helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design" version="3.2.23" id="1">
    <property name="createdBy">Eclipse BIRT Designer Version 4.6.0.v201606072122</property>
    <property name="units">in</property>
    <property name="iconFile">/templates/blank_report.gif</property>
    <property name="bidiLayoutOrientation">ltr</property>
    <property name="imageDPI">120</property>
    <parameters>
        <scalar-parameter name="FileName" id="11">
            <property name="hidden">true</property>
            <property name="valueType">static</property>
            <property name="dataType">string</property>
            <property name="distinct">true</property>
            <simple-property-list name="defaultValue">
                <value type="constant">C:\Users\1122335\Desktop\Workspace\test\new207.xml</value>
            </simple-property-list>
            <list-property name="selectionList"/>
            <property name="paramType">simple</property>
            <property name="controlType">text-box</property>
            <structure name="format">
                <property name="category">Unformatted</property>
            </structure>
        </scalar-parameter>
    </parameters>
    <data-sources>
        <script-data-source name="Data Source" id="9"/>
    </data-sources>
    <data-sets>
        <script-data-set name="Data Set" id="12">
            <list-property name="resultSetHints">
                <structure>
                    <property name="position">1</property>
                    <property name="name">year</property>
                    <property name="dataType">integer</property>
                </structure>
                <structure>
                    <property name="position">2</property>
                    <property name="name">info</property>
                    <property name="dataType">string</property>
                </structure>
                <structure>
                    <property name="position">3</property>
                    <property name="name">category</property>
                    <property name="dataType">string</property>
                </structure>
                <structure>
                    <property name="position">4</property>
                    <property name="name">title</property>
                    <property name="dataType">string</property>
                </structure>
                <structure>
                    <property name="position">5</property>
                    <property name="name">author</property>
                    <property name="dataType">string</property>
                </structure>
                <structure>
                    <property name="position">6</property>
                    <property name="name">country</property>
                    <property name="dataType">string</property>
                </structure>
            </list-property>
            <list-property name="columnHints">
                <structure>
                    <property name="columnName">year</property>
                    <text-property name="displayName">year</text-property>
                </structure>
                <structure>
                    <property name="columnName">info</property>
                    <text-property name="displayName">info</text-property>
                </structure>
                <structure>
                    <property name="columnName">category</property>
                    <text-property name="displayName">category</text-property>
                </structure>
                <structure>
                    <property name="columnName">title</property>
                    <text-property name="displayName">title</text-property>
                </structure>
                <structure>
                    <property name="columnName">author</property>
                    <text-property name="displayName">author</text-property>
                </structure>
                <structure>
                    <property name="columnName">country</property>
                    <text-property name="displayName">country</text-property>
                </structure>
            </list-property>
            <structure name="cachedMetaData">
                <list-property name="resultSet">
                    <structure>
                        <property name="position">1</property>
                        <property name="name">year</property>
                        <property name="dataType">integer</property>
                    </structure>
                    <structure>
                        <property name="position">2</property>
                        <property name="name">info</property>
                        <property name="dataType">string</property>
                    </structure>
                    <structure>
                        <property name="position">3</property>
                        <property name="name">category</property>
                        <property name="dataType">string</property>
                    </structure>
                    <structure>
                        <property name="position">4</property>
                        <property name="name">title</property>
                        <property name="dataType">string</property>
                    </structure>
                    <structure>
                        <property name="position">5</property>
                        <property name="name">author</property>
                        <property name="dataType">string</property>
                    </structure>
                    <structure>
                        <property name="position">6</property>
                        <property name="name">country</property>
                        <property name="dataType">string</property>
                    </structure>
                </list-property>
            </structure>
            <property name="dataSource">Data Source</property>
            <method name="open"><![CDATA[importPackage(javax.xml.parsers);
importPackage(javax.xml.xpath);
importPackage(org.w3c.dom);
importPackage(org.xml.sax);

var factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
var builder = null;
 doc = null;
var expr = null;

factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
//doc = builder.parse("C:\Users\1122335\Desktop\Workspace\test\new207.xml");
doc = builder.parse(params["FileName"].value);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

// create an XPathFactory
var xFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

// create an XPath object
 xpath = xFactory.newXPath();

// compile the XPath expression
expr = xpath.compile("/library/*");
// run the query and get a nodeset
var result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

//initialize object variables to be used in the fetch method
nodes = result;

x = 0;
y = 0;

cnt = nodes.getLength();
]]></method>
            <method name="fetch"><![CDATA[var lboolAllowed = false;

if (x < cnt)
{

    var nodeList = nodes.item(x).getChildNodes();
    var nodeListLength = nodes.item(x).getChildNodes().getLength();
    for(var i=0; i<nodeListLength; i++)
    {
        var nodeName = nodeList.item(i).getNodeName();
        var nodeText = nodeList.item(i).getTextContent();
        if(nodeName == "@category")
        {
            row["category"] = nodeText;
        }
        if(nodeName == "year")
        {
            row["year"] = nodeText;
        }
        else if(nodeName == "info")
        {
            row["info"] = nodeText;
        }
        else if(nodeName == "//title")
        {
        row["title"] = nodeText;
        }
        else if(nodeName == "//author")
        {
        row["author"] = nodeText;
        }
        else if(nodeName == "//country")
        {
        row["country"] = nodeText;
        }

        y++
    }   
    x++;
    y=0;
    return (true);

    }
return (false);]]></method>
            <method name="close"><![CDATA[factory = null;
builder = null;
doc = null;
expr = null;
builder = null;
xFactory = null;

// create an XPath object
 xpath = null;

result = null;

//initialize object variables to be used in the fetch method
nodes = null;

x = 0;
y = 0;

cnt = null;]]></method>
        </script-data-set>
    </data-sets>
    <page-setup>
        <simple-master-page name="Simple MasterPage" id="2">
            <page-footer>
                <text id="3">
                    <property name="contentType">html</property>
                    <text-property name="content"><![CDATA[<value-of>new Date()</value-of>]]></text-property>
                </text>
            </page-footer>
        </simple-master-page>
    </page-setup>
    <body>
        <table id="356">
            <property name="dataSet">Data Set</property>
            <list-property name="boundDataColumns">
                <structure>
                    <property name="name">year</property>
                    <text-property name="displayName">year</text-property>
                    <expression name="expression" type="javascript">dataSetRow["year"]</expression>
                    <property name="dataType">integer</property>
                </structure>
                <structure>
                    <property name="name">info</property>
                    <text-property name="displayName">info</text-property>
                    <expression name="expression" type="javascript">dataSetRow["info"]</expression>
                    <property name="dataType">string</property>
                </structure>
                <structure>
                    <property name="name">category</property>
                    <text-property name="displayName">category</text-property>
                    <expression name="expression" type="javascript">dataSetRow["category"]</expression>
                    <property name="dataType">string</property>
                </structure>
                <structure>
                    <property name="name">title</property>
                    <text-property name="displayName">title</text-property>
                    <expression name="expression" type="javascript">dataSetRow["title"]</expression>
                    <property name="dataType">string</property>
                </structure>
                <structure>
                    <property name="name">author</property>
                    <text-property name="displayName">author</text-property>
                    <expression name="expression" type="javascript">dataSetRow["author"]</expression>
                    <property name="dataType">string</property>
                </structure>
                <structure>
                    <property name="name">country</property>
                    <text-property name="displayName">country</text-property>
                    <expression name="expression" type="javascript">dataSetRow["country"]</expression>
                    <property name="dataType">string</property>
                </structure>
            </list-property>
            <column id="390"/>
            <column id="391"/>
            <column id="392"/>
            <column id="393"/>
            <column id="394"/>
            <column id="395"/>
            <header>
                <row id="357">
                    <cell id="358">
                        <label id="359">
                            <text-property name="text">year</text-property>
                        </label>
                    </cell>
                    <cell id="360">
                        <label id="361">
                            <text-property name="text">info</text-property>
                        </label>
                    </cell>
                    <cell id="362">
                        <label id="363">
                            <text-property name="text">category</text-property>
                        </label>
                    </cell>
                    <cell id="364">
                        <label id="365">
                            <text-property name="text">title</text-property>
                        </label>
                    </cell>
                    <cell id="366">
                        <label id="367">
                            <text-property name="text">author</text-property>
                        </label>
                    </cell>
                    <cell id="368">
                        <label id="369">
                            <text-property name="text">country</text-property>
                        </label>
                    </cell>
                </row>
            </header>
            <detail>
                <row id="370">
                    <cell id="371">
                        <data id="372">
                            <property name="resultSetColumn">year</property>
                        </data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell id="373">
                        <data id="374">
                            <property name="resultSetColumn">info</property>
                        </data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell id="375">
                        <data id="376">
                            <property name="resultSetColumn">category</property>
                        </data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell id="377">
                        <data id="378">
                            <property name="resultSetColumn">title</property>
                        </data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell id="379">
                        <data id="380">
                            <property name="resultSetColumn">author</property>
                        </data>
                    </cell>
                    <cell id="381">
                        <data id="382">
                            <property name="resultSetColumn">country</property>
                        </data>
                    </cell>
                </row>
            </detail>
            <footer>
                <row id="383">
                    <cell id="384"/>
                    <cell id="385"/>
                    <cell id="386"/>
                    <cell id="387"/>
                    <cell id="388"/>
                    <cell id="389"/>
                </row>
            </footer>
        </table>
    </body>
</report>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an XML/DOM related issue: `nodeName` does not have `@` or `//` as prefix (that is XPath stuff) but just the element or attribute name, so not `@category` but just `category`, remove them in

```
   if(nodeName == "@category")
```

and

```
   else if(nodeName == "//author")
    {
    row["author"] = nodeText;
    }
    else if(nodeName == "//country")
    {
    row["country"] = nodeText;
    }
```

The table in [DOM Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) javadoc shows what is returned by `Node.getNodeName()`

---

Additionally the nodes where you query category/author/country are wrong, see:

```
var book =  nodes.item(x);
var nodeList = book.getChildNodes();
var nodeListLength = nodeList.getLength();
row["category"] = book.getAttribute("category");
for(int i=0; i<nodeListLength; i++)
{
    var child = nodeList.item(i);
    var nodeName = child.getNodeName();
    var nodeText = child.getTextContent();
    if(nodeName == "year")
    {
        row["year"] = nodeText);
    }
    else if(nodeName == "info")
    {
        row["info"] = nodeText);
    }
    else if(nodeName == "title")
    {
        row["title"] = nodeText);
    }
    else if(nodeName == "author")
    {
        row["author"] =  child.getAttribute("name");
        row["country"] = child.getAttribute("country");
    }
```

Note: author is actually a list

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried your suggestion but they are still showing up blank.